# if i create my database with sql server 2008 r2 management studio

Tags: database

I Create my database with sql server 2008 R2 .
now when setup this software in other computers must install sql server 2008 R2 management studio ?
not exist other way ?

and how i set SqlConnection that run at other systems.
(i connect to database with data connection in visual studio)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Exist other way.  I mean, there are other ways.  Nearly any software that can connect to a database created in SQL Server 7, 2000, 2005 or 2008 is capable of connecting to a database created in SQL Server 2008 R2.

SQL Server Management Studio is used when a human user wants to connect to the database, but not when software connects to it.